# Problem with not highlited and red marked text in Visual Studio Code - Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with not highlighted and red marked text in Visual Studio Code.
Some pictures below:

General overview:

[image: General overview]

Problem in code and not red marked:

[image: Problem in code and not red marked]

Corrected codeS:

[image: Corrected codeS]

Print of corrected code:

[image: Print of corrected code]

Generally:

- Main functionality of Visual Studio Code is meet
- Wrong text is not red marked
- Variables are not blue marked

Settings:

- Color theme: Dark+
- Visual Studio Code 1.83.1
- Python extension v2023.18.0

Other actions I've tried:

- Reinstalled Visual Studio Code (also manually deleted everything in subfolders)
- Reinstalled all extensions (also manually deleted everything in subfolders)

I have no clue what isn't working. Anyway I have tried to do some stuff from other posts which were similar to mine but none of them helped me.

Comment: do either of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77385065/11107541 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/77383931/11107541 answer your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved
Solution: I deprecated my Visual Studio Code to version 1.7 and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the following settings.

```
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Also this may be related to recent [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77383931/vs-code-python-circa-v2023-9-v2023-10-has-reduced-syntax-highlighting-no-snippe).