# Python showing white color for variable names in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I write code in python it shows the variable names in white for some reason
[image: Example code with names being in white]

When I change my settings in VS Code to

```
    "variables": "#f00"
 },
```

it starts showing this instead,

[image]

Which is still not what i want.

I have also tried to uninstall and reinstall my VS Code python extension

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/77385065/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77383931/11107541. this is probably a duplicate of one of those.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @toyotaSupra the screenshots serve an important purpose here. but yes, I'd like to have the code as text in **addition** to the screenshots so I could copy and paste to reproduce.

Comment: You can try rolling back the Pylance extension, for example, version 10.30.